# jquery scroll restriction.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here I am trying to make my two id's `#stop`,`#stop2` be fixed even after scrolling and make my `#stop3` scroll till it reaches `#footer` once it reaches `#footer` both `#stop`,`#stop2` should stop scrolling.here in my case both `#stop`,`#stop2` are scrolling on to the `#footer` which should not happen, I dont know where I am going wrong, any help is accepted.Thank you in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .one{width:100px;border:1px solid #CCC;height:200px;float:left;margin:0px 20px;background:#F00;}
    .footer{width:100%;height:800px;background:#339;clear:both;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="scroller_anchor"></div>
    <div id="stop" class="one"></div>
    <div class="one" id="stop3" style="height:2000px;">

    </div>
    <div id="stop2" class="one"></div>
    <div class="scroller_anchor1"></div>
    <div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {

        var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;
        var scroller_anchor1 = $(".scroller_anchor1").offset().top;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $("#stop,#stop2").css('position') != 'fixed') 
        {    
           $('#stop,#stop2').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0px'
            });
            $('#stop').css({
                'left':'4%'

            });
            $('#stop2').css({
                'right':'2%'
            });
            $('#stop3').css({
                'left':'16.6%'
            });

            $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
        } 

         else if ($(this).scrollTop() > scroller_anchor1 && $('#stop,#stop2').css('position') != 'relative' ) 
        {   
          $('#stop,#stop2,#stop3').css({
                'position': 'relative',
                'left':'inherit',
                'right':'inherit'

            });
        }
        else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('#stop,#stop2').css('position') != 'relative' ) 
        {   
            $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');
          $('#stop,#stop2,#stop3').css({

                'position': 'relative',
                'left':'inherit',
                'right':'inherit'

            });
        }



    });

    </script>
    </html>
```

here is my fiddle  jsfiddle.net/xPdD7

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle? Also could you explain what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @MMM please look at my edited question.and here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xPdD7/

Comment: To me, its still not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could mock up a few small images to show what you expect to happen as you are scrolling?

Comment: as you see in the fiddle when you scroll till the footer(blue) comes both left and right red blocks get on to the footer which should not happen.both the red blocks should stop above the footer..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your js code a little bit for testing purposes, but all the hardcoded values can be changed to your particular needs:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {

        var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;
        var scroller_anchor1 = $(".scroller_anchor1").offset().top;
        var footer = $(".footer").offset().top;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $("#stop,#stop2").css('position') != 'fixed') 
        {    
           $('#stop,#stop2').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '8px'
            });
            $('#stop2').css({
                'left':'280px'
            });
            $('#stop3').css({
                'left':'140px'
            });        }
        if (($(this).scrollTop()+200) > footer  ) 
        {
          $('#stop,#stop2').css({
              'position':'absolute',
              'top':'1800px'
            });
        }      
    });
```

Also here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xPdD7/8/

Is this what you are trying to achieve?